# Eloquent - How should I make a condition in a join table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a tournament table.

Each tournament hasMany Championships.

I want to get the tournament that match the championshipID = 333.

So, I do it :

```
$tournament = Tournament::with([
            'championships' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('id', '=', 333);
            },
            'championships.settings',
            'championships.category',
            'championships.tree.user1',
            'championships.tree.user2',
            'championships.tree.user3',
            'championships.tree.user4',
            'championships.tree.user5'
        ])->first();
```

Example of 1 of my relations:

```
 public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ChampionshipSettings::class);
}
```

Tell me if you need all, to post it.

But as I put 1 eager loading relationship, I get all my tournaments instead of getting just one.

What Am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `whereHas()` which will allow you to filter a model based on a related model's constraints.  You should also use a subquery for the nested constraints if you're getting the related model more than once to avoid query duplication like:

```
$tournament = Tournament::whereHas('championships', function($query) use ($championshipId) {
                    return $query->where('id', $championshipId);
                })
                ->with(['championships' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->where('id', '=', 333)
                        ->with([
                            'settings',
                            'category',
                            'tree' => function($query) {
                                return $query->with('user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5');
                            }]); 
                }])
                ->first();
```